# Loop over sibling elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform some XML into HTML via xslt. I have been struggling to find a way that will let me loop over two sibling elements simultaneously.

I'm working with XML that looks like this:

```
<Response>
  <SearchParams/>
    <LastName>Kent</LastName>
  </SearchParams>
  <Result>
    <LastName>Clark</LastName>
  </Result>
  <SearchParams/>
    <LastName>Wayne</LastName>
  </SearchParams>
  <Result>
    <FirstName>Bruce</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Martha</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Thomas</FirstName>
  </Result>
  <SearchParams/>
    <FirstName>Odinson</FirstName>
  </SearchParams>
  <Result>
    <FirstName>Thor</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Loki</FirstName>
  </Result>
</Response>
```

I want to be able to loop over the `SearchParams` and its sibling `Result` simultaneously and combine data from them in the output HTML.

```
<div>
  Results for search on Kent: Clark
</div>
<div>
  Results for search on Wanye: Bruce, Martha, Thomas
</div>
<div>
  Results for search on Odinson: Thor, Loki
</div>
```

I've been through a number of other answers on StackOverflow, but none seem to address this specific problem. I first tried exploring the `for-each-group` methods, but they seem to be more catered to sibling elements of the same key. The next thing I was going to see if there is a way to combine `SearchParams` and `Results` into one element first, and then extract values from that element.

The most helpful thing would just be a push in the right direction as to what xsl methods I should be considering for this problem. Working with xsl is not something my team normally does, so this is mainly a one-off problem that we don't have a lot of institutional knowledge about.

Comment: Your use of `<Result/>` and `</Result>` in the input is not well-formed XML. As for the problem, yes, use `for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="SearchParams"`, see the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for a start.

Comment: If every `SearchParams` has exactly one `Result` then this is very simple: process all `SearchParams` and get additional data from `following-sibling::Result[1]`.

Comment: Finney, what is your XSLT version?

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo! I wrote this at the end of my work day, and it seems my brain was a bit tired.

@MartinHonnen will give the `for-each-group` another go. Thanks for the link to some additional info on this.

@michael.hor257k I'll also give `following-sibling` a shot if I can't get `for-each-group` to work.

@YitzhakKhabinsky - I believe I can use any version I want, but I am working with 2.0 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MartinHonnen pointed out, your XML is not well-formed.
First, I had to fix it.

Assuming that your XSLT is 2.0, and following @michael.hor257k suggestion, please find below working XSLT.

**XML**

```
<Response>
    <SearchParams>
        <LastName>Kent</LastName>
    </SearchParams>
    <Result>
        <LastName>Clark</LastName>
    </Result>
    <SearchParams>
        <LastName>Wayne</LastName>
    </SearchParams>
    <Result>
        <FirstName>Bruce</FirstName>
        <FirstName>Martha</FirstName>
        <FirstName>Thomas</FirstName>
    </Result>
    <SearchParams>
        <FirstName>Odinson</FirstName>
    </SearchParams>
    <Result>
        <FirstName>Thor</FirstName>
        <FirstName>Loki</FirstName>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Response">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="SearchParams/*">
                <div> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Results for search on ', ., ': ', string-join(../following-sibling::Result[1]/*,', '))"/>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <div>Results for search on Kent: Clark</div>
  <div>Results for search on Wayne: Bruce, Martha, Thomas</div>
  <div>Results for search on Odinson: Thor, Loki</div>
</root>
```

Comment: `string-join` is a function introduced in XPath 2.0 so it is supported by XSLT 2 or later processors but certainly not by XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

3.0 solution, assuming corrections to typos in your input:

```
<xsl:template match="SearchParams">
  <div>Results for search on {SearchParams/*}: {string-join(following-sibling::Result[1]/*, ', ')}</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `following-sibling::Result/*` returns **all** following names, not just the ones in the immediately following `Result`.